# Does Chrome share WebAudio implementation with Safari and all WebKit-based browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, chromium, web-audio-api

I'm looking at the Chromium project and the implementation for Web Audio seems to be in the "src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webaudio" dir.

Comment: For now it seems that they do. However Chrome has forked WebKit into Blink, so it's entirely possible that the implementations will diverge at some point.

Comment: Well, that's kind of what I am trying to find out. And it's not clear, since it's still in WebKit. Also, I don't think there is too much sense for diverging at all - I don't think there will be anything Chrome-specific in the WA implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Chrome no longer shares the implementation with all WebKit-based browsers.  Chrome used to, but it forked WebKit to Blink and the implementations are now separate.

Having said that, I think most of the implementation is still similar, but it is diverging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see that you are a developer in the Chrome project, so I am sure you're right, but why does it reside in a dir called thirdParty, if it has diverged already?

Comment: Because it's a lot of work to move/rename everything and update all the paths.  All while many people are committing changes constantly.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks.